# How to generate variable pitch helix in nurbs form

Tags: geometry, 3d, spline

I would like to define a helix with a

- start pitch
- end pitch
- start radius
- end radius
- start angle

[image]

The pitch and radius parameters should be interpolated linearly from each end along the length of the helix.

My aim is to create a NURBS curve that closely matches this helix with the smallest number of control points I need. My geometry library has a function for directly generating nurbs curves from knot vectors and ctrlPoints.

```
NurbsCurve Create(int degree, double[] knotVector, Point4D[] ctrlPoints);
```

What is the math required to generated these parameters?

Comment: A helix cannot be exactly represented as a NURBS curve. So, you will have to approximate it.

Comment: He said "closely matches", which implies approximation (to me).